# Казусы сервера который выводит содержимое PHP как есть

Tags: php, joomla, веб-сервер

Собираю лендинг на Joomla ничего не предвещает беды, вроде все сделал, но тут решил протестировать отправку писем из форм заказа. Отправляю форму и вижу сюрприз:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но письмо пришло. Может кто-нибудь объяснить почему сервер выдал мне весь PHP код как есть. Обращаюсь по прямой ссылке, тоже самое получаю. Открываю исходный код страница - ПУСТО.

НО самое интересное, что я этот файл уже поменял, изменил данные авторизации по SMTP, но здесь я вижу старые данные.

Открываю в режиме инкогнито - ПУСТО.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:D Я понял в чем дело ребята.
У меня в Chrome DevTools был включен "Local Overrides" и я не подумав скачал mail.php в папку с хранившимися там временными файлами этого сайта. Поэтому при обращению к сайту Хром мне выдавал не то что видит на сервере а то, что у меня в этой папке)